# How to join next line if certain character is there in AWK?

Tags: awk

In a text file (windows) i have:

```
sometexthere"
nothingtodohere
yessomethinghere"
etc
```

Using AWK (in Ubuntu) how to delete the apostrophe " at the end of the line, replace it with a semi colon : and join the next line?

so it looks like this:

```
sometexthere:nothingtodohere
yessomethinghere:etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way:

```
awk '1' RS='"\n' ORS=':' yourfile
```

Just set your record sep. to double quotes plus break line, and your output record sep. to the join character.

For `DOS` *line breaks* just adjust the `regex`:

```
awk '1' RS='"\r\n' ORS=':' yourfile
```

**Note**: what that `1` means?

Short answer, It's just a *shortcut* to avoid using the print statement. In awk when a condition gets matched the default action is to print the input line, example:

```
$ echo "test" |awk '1'
test
```

That's because `1` will be always [true](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Truth-Values-and-Conditions), so this expression is equivalent to:

```
$ echo "test"|awk '1==1'
test
$ echo "test"|awk '{if (1==1){print}}'
test
```

Comment: nope, still exactly the same (ubuntu), copy and paste the example in a file and test it.

Comment: argh, sorry i added extra infor to the question, (the text file is a windows text file), & i'm using AWK in Ubuntu... does that info help at all?

Comment: thanks, it's perfect answer. I got a lot to learn, I'm starting to read awk books :)